How can I set a custom Kafka message key when using Flink KafkaSink in Python?
I wrote a Flink Python application using the DataStream API that publishes messages to Kafka using KafkaSink.
Stream elements are dictionaries formatted as:
{
  "name": "alice",
  "id": "1"
}

I would like to set the Kafka message key to be the value for the element "name". For example, the above stream element should be published to Kafka as a message with the key alice and the value {"name":"alice","id":"1"}. How can I achieve this?
My attempt, using the following code, resulted in Kafka messages containing {"name":"alice","id":"1"} for both the key and the value.
import json
import os

from pyflink.common.serialization import SimpleStringSchema
from pyflink.common.typeinfo import Types
from pyflink.datastream import StreamExecutionEnvironment
from pyflink.datastream.connectors.kafka import (
    KafkaRecordSerializationSchema,
    KafkaSink,
)


HERE = os.path.dirname(os.path.realpath(__file__))
JAR_PATH = os.path.join(HERE, "flink-sql-connector-kafka-3.0.2-1.18.jar")


def main():
    env = StreamExecutionEnvironment.get_execution_environment()
    env.add_jars(f"file://{JAR_PATH}")

    stream = env.from_collection(
        [
            {"name": "alice", "id": "1"},
            {"name": "bob", "id": "2"},
            {"name": "charlie", "id": "3"}
        ],
        Types.MAP(Types.STRING(), Types.STRING()),
    ).key_by(lambda x: x["name"])

    record_serializer = (
        KafkaRecordSerializationSchema.builder()
        .set_topic("jonathan_schnabel_test_output")
        .set_value_serialization_schema(SimpleStringSchema())
        .set_key_serialization_schema(SimpleStringSchema())
        .build()
    )

    producer = (
        KafkaSink.builder()
        .set_bootstrap_servers("localhost:9092")
        .set_record_serializer(record_serializer)
        .build()
    )

    stream.map(lambda x: json.dumps(x), Types.STRING()).sink_to(producer)

    env.execute()


if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()


I am using the following tool versions:

Python: 3.10.12
apache-flink Python library: 1.18.1
Flink SQL connector Kafka JAR: flink-sql-connector-kafka-3.0.2-1.18

In similar Stackoverflow questions (link, and link), it was suggested to implement custom serialization classes to get full control on Kafka message keys. However, these questions address Java and Scala applications.
